# mod_write RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

im sure this is simple but i totally cant get it to work :\
I'm trying to rewrite

`http://www.example.com/products/ABC123`

to

`http://www.example.com/index.php?page=shop&code=ABC123`

I have tried

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=shop&code=$1
```

Which redirects OK but all the images (and js css etc) have the wrong path (example.com/images/ABC123.jpg is example.com/products/images/ABC123.jpg). Also all of the links are now the wrong path (example.com/?page=shop&folder=7 is example.com/products/?page=shop&folder=7)

My .htaccess file is in the root, I have also tried RewriteBase products/ and removing products/ from the rules regex but that just throws a 404

I've read the official docs concerning mod_rewrite several times in the last hour, I must be missing something?

** EDIT: **
Sorry all was a bit of a trick question, turns out you can solve this with the html BASE element, there was nothing wrong with my regex at the start!

I put <base href="http://www.example.com/" /> in the HEAD section and it's all fine and dandy now!

Thanks to the guys who showed me how to set conditions for weather or not the file/directory exists

Comment: Btw, I also found someone suggesting that I put RewriteCond !\.(js|css|png|jpg)$ which seems to be a valid regex, but this makes the server throw a 500 error :S

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^products/([-a-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?page=shop&code=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: sorry, this didnt seem to have any effect

Comment: Would you please give some details pls like what is not working? Are your image/css files still getting redirected even with above rules? May I know your absolute path of image/css files? Also your web server's access log may also help me give you better answer.

Comment: Maybe the case insensitivity has some effect on the variable?? But else the rewrite is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /

      # Generic requests for the application
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ index.php?page=shop&code=$1 [L]
```

That do it?

EDIT: Ah, well, your in-page links being wrong is something you should probably fix in PHP. You might try this:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Generic requests for the application
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Main page
    RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=shop&code=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^products/?(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

    # Resources
    RewriteRule ^products/images/(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^products/css/(.*)$ css/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^products/js/(.*)$ js/$1 [L]
```

But really, you should generate your URLs in php so they work right: would be more efficient than having to run them through mod_rewrite every time.

Comment: nope same problem sorry, product pages have no css, js or images

Comment: Awesome thanks this didnt help directly but i had the idea to look up relative url rewriting which lead me to the html BASE element, i think thats what i was looking for